# Solve the following equation for real $y$

Tags: functions

Ok, here is another problem I also need help with.
Solve the equation for real y: 
$$2\sqrt[3]{(2y-1)} = y^3 +1$$
This is done by defining $$f(y) = \frac{(y^3+1)}{2}$$
So, the equation becomes $$y=\frac{(f(y)^3+1)}{2} = f(f(y))$$
And, then it says since f is monotonically increasing, $f(y) = y$, and the equation is then $$y^3 -2y+1 = 0$$

And, $y = 1, y = -1.61803, y = 0.618034$.

Now, Here are my questions. 1. Why do you have to define this as a function? 2. How did you come up with $$y=\frac{(f(y)^3+1)}{2} = f(f(y)),$$ and 3. Can you do this directly without defining it as a function?

Comment: So, here is my way of doing this problem...Let,$\sqrt[3]{(2y-1)} = x$. Then, $(2y - 1) = x^3 => 2y = x^3 + 1 => y = (x^3 + 1) / 2$. And, if we substitute the value of x into out real equation we get, $$2x = (\frac{(x^3+1)}{2})^3 + 1$$ After expanding this we get, $$x^9+3x^6+3x^2-16x+1 = 0$$.Any suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x = (y^3+1)/2$, you'll have

$$ \sqrt[3]{2y-1} = x$$
$$ x^3 = 2y - 1$$
$$ y = \frac{x^3+1}{2}$$

Turn this into a system of equations:

$$ 2y = x^3 + 1 $$
$$ 2x = y^3 + 1 $$

To solve, subtract the second equation from the first:

$$ 2(y-x) = x^3 - y^3 $$
$$ 2(y-x) + (y-x)(x^2 + xy + y^2) = 0 $$
$$ (y-x)(2+x^2+xy+y^2) = 0 $$

Since $x^2+xy+y^2 = (x+\frac{y}{2})^2 + \frac{3y^2}{4} > 0 \quad \forall (x, y)$, the only solution is $y - x = 0$, therefore $x = y$

Substitute back:

$$ 2y = y^3 + 1 $$
$$ y^3 - 2y + 1 = 0 $$

Comment: Can you please explain the part says "the only solution is $x-y = 0$", or is it  the same as $y-x=0$? Thanks.

Comment: I meant $y - x = 0$, but yes it's the same.

Comment: Ok thanks. Just to make sure I am on the right track :)

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to show that you can express the solution as $y = f(f(y))$ where $f$ is increasing, i.e. $f(y) \geq y$. If that's the case then if $f(y) > y$ then $f(f(y)) \geq f(y) > y$ and so if $f(f(y)) = y$ then $f(y) = y$. This kind of situation rarely comes up in practice, this is a contrived equation with a very special solution approach.

Comment: Wow! that is tricky. I was hoping there is an easier approach to do this problem.